# limit scope of multi-character wildcard in REGEX

Tags: mysql, regex

I have strings containing sequences like these:

```
^^fruit/citrus^fruit/citrus/orange^meat^vegetables/carrot^^
^^fruit/citrus^vegetables^vegetables/carrot^^
^^fruit/citrus/orange^vegetables/carrot^^
^^fruit/citrus/lemon^vegetables/potatoe^^
```

Steps in a sequence are separated with ^ character.

I would like to be able to use a multi-character wildcard to search those strings, but the wildcard should work only within a scope of a step. For example this pseudo-query:

`^^[fruit/*]^vegetables/*^^`

Should match all seqences starting with any step starting with "fruit/" followed by a step starting with "vegetables/". So these should be matched:

```
^^fruit/citrus/orange^vegetables/carrot^^
^^fruit/citrus/orange^vegetables/potatoe^^
```

but not these:

```
^^fruit/citrus^fruit/citrus/orange^meat^vegetables/carrot^^
^^fruit/citrus^vegetables^vegetables/carrot^^
```

Is there a way to this in MySQL (5.6 or 8.0) REGEX? Where do I get started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the regex like

```
^\^{2}fruit/[^^]*\^vegetables/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LU3qaj/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\^{2}` - `^^` substring
- `fruit/` - fixed text
- `[^^]*` - zero or more chars other than `^`
- `\^vegetables/` - a `^vegetables/` string.

In MySQL, remember to use double backslashes in regex escapes (`"^\\^{2}fruit/[^^]*\\^vegetables/"`). Something like `SELECT col from table1 WHERE col REGEXP "^\\^{2}fruit/[^^]*\\^vegetables/"`.

Comment: Thank you, I simplified the query to: '\^\^fruit/[^^]*\^vegetables/' and it works as needed! I just don't understand why there are two ^ in '[^^]*'?

Comment: @Khan `[^^]` is a negated character class (`[^...]`) that matches any char other than the one defined in it. Since there is only one `^`, this matches any char other than a `^` char.